# Build CAML query by value from ClientPeoplePicker

Tags: client-object-model, 2013, caml

I use these lines of code:

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker ID="clpUser" runat="server" UseLocalSuggestionCache="True"/>
```

JS:

```
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[clientId + "_TopSpan"];
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();

var expressions = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    expressions.push("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Absentee'></FieldRef><Value Type='User'>" + users[i].DisplayText + "</Value></Eq>");
}

var query = buidQueryFromExpressions(expressions);
```

My problem is for several users ClientPeoplePicker returns values that represent login (domain/username), but for the CAML query I should use display name or ID, because in my list that stores the data the user display name is used. How can I correctly configure this control? May be you know other solutions?

Comment: Looks like you found an answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58866/how-to-load-several-users-by-array-of-login-names-csom

Comment: @JussiPalo, I'm thinking about my solution as workaround. I don't like it. I would like to find better solution :)

Comment: Using that hidden User Information List to get the ID has been a workaround since SP 2007 so I'm guessing it is now a solution :)

Comment: @JussiPalo, plz put your comment as an answer, I will select it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hidden User Information List to get the ID has been a workaround since SP 2007 so it's basically a solution for this.