# How to load several users by array of login names CSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

I have a dynamically created array of user logins, I would like to retrieve information about these users through CSOM. I found this [great post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185012%28v=office.14%29.aspx), but there is explanation how to retrieve all users from group. How can I specify that I need to retrieve info only for users in my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my project I used User Information List, but I don't think that it is a good solution

```
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[clientId + "_TopSpan"];
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();

var _ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

var expressions = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    expressions.push("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + users[i].Key + "</Value></Eq>");
}

var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where>" + buidQueryFromExpressions(expressions) + "</Where></Query></View>");

var list = _ctx.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();

_loadUsers = list.getItems(query);

_ctx.load(_loadUsers);
```

Comment: Trying to do this very thing but in JSOM...for an Office 365 app, great post.

Comment: When i run this i get an error buidQueryFromExpressions is not defined, is this because you are using CSOM and I'm JSOM?

Comment: @Stephen, no. It is a custom function which combine expressions with `<or>` tag.