# Retrieve a list item based on People picker App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, jsom

I have a list which contains an Employee column of a Type person or group.  I have built a page which contains a people picker and nothing else.

When the user selects a user from the PeoplePicker, i want to get that user from the above list and display all the items...

Is this possible using JSOM and Sharepoint 2013 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use client side PeoplePicker (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713593.aspx)) that will give data of the selected user. You can use that data to query for the items on the People list.

As Client Side PeoplePicker won't return user ID; you need to do additional query   to hidden User Information List to get the site collection specific user ID, see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58866/how-to-load-several-users-by-array-of-login-names-csom). You should be able to use the ["Key" value](http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/imagelibrary/120904/PickerEntityData.png) you get of the user from client side PeoplePicker as it maps to the "Name" column of the hidden user list.

Comment: Thanks Jussi...yes I am using that example and have got it working to a point. I'm totally new to JSOM so trying to learn as I go along. I get all the selected data but not sure to isolate the DisplayText or even get the accountID/UserID

Comment: Updated my answer above.